# ¿Cómo darle formato de fecha (__/__/____) a un textbox dentro de un datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy trabajando con una columna de `DataGridView` tipo caja de texto. Esta no tiene para formato fecha, por lo que me gustaría que tuviese el formato `--/--/----` (con las barras de separación) desde el principio, para no tener que escribirlo cada vez que lo necesite.

He buscado y probado, pero no he encontrado nada que me pueda servir.

Comment: Por defecto creo que no existe nada. [Aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox) tienes un control que puede servirte

Comment: Todo depende del resultado final que quieres. Como ha dicho @Pikoh en el control `DataGridView` no viene incluido algo como el `MaskedTextbox` a la hora de editar los datos. Pero si puedes trabajar con la propiedad `.Format` para que el formato de los datos sea el que tu quieres, solo que no se verá exactamente como un Masked.

Answer (score 2):

El DataGridView es un control con funcionalidad bastante básica pero que está diseñado para permitir una gran extensibilidad.

De esta forma puedes crearte tus propios formatos de celdas y columnas.

Para crearte una celda de tipo fecha con ayuda de edición básicamente tendrías que crearte:

Una clase que implemente la interfaz `IDataGridViewEditingControl` que encapsule la funcionalidad del control de edición.

Una clase que herede de `DataGridViewCell` para el comportamiento de la celda.

Y una clase que herede de `DataGridViewColumn` para implementar el tipo de columna fecha.

Puedes encontrar multitud de ejemplos en internet, por ejemplo aquí tienes uno que encapsula el control `DateTimePicker` dentro del control de edición de la celda:

[Windows Forms. DataGridView. Columna con editor de fechas](http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/datagridview-columna-fechas.html)